# Why are they showing syntax error for the given query?

Tags: mysql

```
USE sql_store;

SELECT *
FROM order_items
WHERE order = 6  AND (unit_price * quantity) > 30
```

Look at the below image.

[image]

I tried finding what might have went wrong but I couldn't.

NOTE: I am a beginner and I started learning SQL recently.

EDIT: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`order` is a reserved word (as part of the `order by` clause). If you want to use it for a column name, you'll have to escape it by using backticks:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   order_items
WHERE  `order` = 6  AND (unit_price * quantity) > 30
-- Here^-----^
```

Comment: Please check edit. It doesn't seem like working.

Comment: @Kaushik the error message is quite straight forward - it seems like there is no such column. Can you share the definition of the table?

Comment: Oops, I'm sorry! I got it now. Thanks for your help!